# Different behaviour PF select one menu JSF selectOnemenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am experiencing a problem with the use of primefaces selectOneMenu. I am having a menu getting its selectItems values from a backing bean. The container of the menu is updated by ajax. Useing primefaces menu, all the items are lost after the update, using standard JSF Menu, all the items look fine.

XHTML:

```
  <p:outputPanel id="myContainer" widgetVar="myContainerVar">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{somePresenter.renderBox}">
      <h:selectOneMenu id="mySelectMenu"     
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" 
        value="#{somePresenter.someObject}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{somePresenter.someObjectList}" 
          var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item}" /> 
      </h:selectOneMenu>

      <p:selectOneMenu id="mySelectMenuP" 
        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
        value="#{somePresenter.someObject}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{somePresenter.someObjectList}" 
          var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item}" /> 
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:outputPanel>
  </p:outputPanel>

<p:commandLink action="#{somePresenter.doIt()}" update="myContainer"
value="doIt!" />
```

Bean:

```
@Getter
@Setter
private SomeObject someObject;

@Getter
@Setter
private Boolean renderBox = true;

public List<SomeObject> getObjectList(){
  return objectBoundary.getList();
}

public void doIt(){ this.renderBox = !this.renderBox; }
```

When the page is first displayed, both menus are filled with Items. However, as soon as I close and open the container (press command link twice), the h:selectOneMenu still looks fine while the p:selectOneMenu has lost all its Items.

I have taken a closer look using googles developer tools, both menus have the items as options. The p-menu just seems not to be correctly rendered.

[image: Weird OneMenu behaviour]

I am experiencing exactly the same Problem when using Enums instead of the shown Objects. The presenter is @Named and @ViewScoped.

I would really appreciate any help since I am stucked with this for quite some time now. Thank you in advance!

--- edit ---

I am using Primefaces version 4.0 and JSF version 2.2

--- edit ---

Upgrading to PF 5.3 makes the menu look slightly different:

[Slightly different menu after upgrade to PF 5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvitK.png)

Comment: known issue in PrimeFaces 0.9.6 and having these `id="myContainer" widgetVar="myContainer"` identical is bad practice

Comment: I have changed the widgetVar to differ from the ID. Sadly, the issue still exists. I also added PF and JSF versions for clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Try switching the two... does it work differently then? And are you **sure** you don't have any errors? You use the same ID twice

Comment: By switching you mean switching the position? I have tried that without a result. The two same IDs are actually a copy paste error - Sorry for that. Fixed it here.

Comment: Pay more attention next time with code... Did you try (just try) PrimeFaces 5.0 or 5.1 or 5.2 or 5.3 with this simple example?

Comment: I have upgraded the project to Primefaces 5.3. The menu looks slightly different, but still has no options. I have added a screenshot showing the menu with PF 5.3